# Are there any Payment Gateway available in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, payment-gateway, payment-processing

i am developing E-Commerce Application in which i want Payment gateway for  Credit card Transaction..

Comment: What would you think? it's a major platform. Use google before asking on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can integrate Many Payment getway availabe online.

some of them are following

1. SagePay
2. Paypal
3. RealEx
4. Barclay

any many more...

Answer (score 1):

Authorize.Net is a good one too.